# iOS push notification not working on app store build where as working on test push

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

This is regarding a push notification services.

One of my app is not receiving push notifications after an update which it was receiving before the update. I have tried all the troubleshooting techniques provided by apple and resubmitted the app as well but helpless.

Following test cases I have executed.

- Renew the Push certificate and updated PEM file with server.
- Re submitted the app by validating distribution profile and push certificates.
- App is not supporting iOS 10 upgrade, So entitlement file is not added in build.
- Server receiving a token from the App successfully and notification feedback also succeeded.

Back end server run on Ruby on rails using APN_on_rails GEM for push.

My only concern is I am getting push notification in my app(downloaded from App Store) when manually sent as test badges from the same server but same is not getting pushed when sent from live scenario.

Post if you need any other details to look into this further.

Please help me on this, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us the payload that you're sending to APNS?

Comment: Payload will be {"aps" => {"badge" => 5}}  , use the library [apn_on_rails](https://github.com/PRX/apn_on_rails/blob/master/lib/apn_on_rails/app/models/apn/notification.rb). Thanks for your interest on this @jarora

Comment: This looks fine. You're not sending any title and body, so you won't see any notification and you would only see a badge. Is that desired? Also, you're sure that you're getting the push notification token on your server?

Comment: Yes, app needs only badge and server getting push token as well. Using that token I used to test and validate the PEM file.

Comment: According to [APNS connection lost](https://github.com/grocer/grocer/issues/14), I suspect on the apns connection lost. Since my server having one crore APNS token in which around 2k of tokens are valid. So most of the request to APNS might be invalid or contains bad token which might disconnect the connection to APNS.   
So the minimal number of valid devices are not getting push notifications. any comments?

Comment: There is a way to check if an app is installed on a device. Please see this https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/BinaryProviderAPI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH13-SW12